# Need the highest dir of the URL

Tags: java, string, url, path, directory

`new URL("http://example.com/public/files/random.php")`

I want to fetch the highest directory of the URL when the URL ends with a file extension. For ex: that URL ends with `.php` so I want to fetch `http://example.com/public/files/` from that. Is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: do you need help with the string conversion or fetching the actual data? Either way, most servers don't allow you to browse a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for the address `String` minus the `PHP` page, you could use `URI#resolve` instead

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://example.com/public/files/random.php");
String noPage = uri.resolve("").toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/public/files/random.php");
String urlString = url.toString();
String fetched = urlString.substring(0, urlString.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

this finds the last slash and cuts the String there. If the URL doesn't end with an file extension, like "http://example.com/public/", then the last occurence of '/' is exactly the last character in the String, so nothing changes.